# Tight lower bound on the number of triangles in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Show that the minimum number of triangles is at least
> \begin{equation*}
>     \frac{4m}{3n}\left(m-\frac{n^2}{4}\right).
> \end{equation*}
> Prove that the bound is tight when $m=n^2/3$.

I managed to prove the first part. I am having trouble showing why a graph with $n^2/3$ edges has $n^3/27$ triangles (using the bound). I thought about constructing complete bipartite graphs and then adding the remaining edges until I hit $n^2/3$. However, I am getting more triangles than I'm supposed to.

---

My proof of the first part.

Given an edge $(u,v)\in E(G)$, there are at least $d_u + d_v - 2 - (n-2) = d_u + d_v - n$ triangles including the edge $(u,v)$. Hence, the minimum number of triangles is given by
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{(u,v)\in E}\frac{d_u+d_v-n}{3} = \frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{u\in V}d_u^2 - mn\right).
\end{equation*}
Applyin Cauchy-Schwarz to the vectors $(d_1,\dots, d_n)$ and $(1,\dots,1)$ we obtain
\begin{equation*}
    n\sum_{u\in V}d_u\geq \left(\sum_{u\in V}d_u\right)^2 = 4m^2 .
\end{equation*}
Therefore, the number of triangles in $G$ is greater than or equal to
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{4m^2}{n}-mn\right) = \frac{4m}{3n}\left(m-\frac{n^2}{4}\right).
\end{equation*}

Comment: 1/ Please include your proof. For such structure finder and avoider questions, the proof will give hints on the construction of the example. $\quad$ 2/ Your interpretation isn't correct, but that's partly because the question isn't phrased all that well. Instead, of  "Equality must hold when $m = n^2/3$.", what it really means is "Equality can hold when $m = n^2/3$ (We cannot tighten the bound further, so we say that the bound is tight.)

Comment: @CalvinLin I see. From now on, I won't forget what "tight" means in these situations. Many thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $m=\frac{n^2}{3}$, $\frac{4m}{3n}(m-\frac{n^2}{4}) = \frac{n^3}{27}$. Indeed, as Calvin Lin points out, showing tightness here means exhibiting a graph with $\frac{n^2}{3}$ edges and $\frac{n^3}{27}$ triangles.

Let us construct such a graph $G$. Observe that $\frac{n^3}{27} = (\frac{n}{3})^3$, so it is not too much of a leap to partition $V(G)$ into sets $V_1, V_2, V_3$ each of size $\frac{n}{3}$ (note that we can assume $3|n$), and making vertices adjacent iff they belong to different sets. Thus, $G$ has $\frac{n^3}{27}$ triangles, formed by selecting a vertex from each $V_i$. The number of edges between $V_1$ and $V_2$ is $(\frac{n}{3})^2 = \frac{n^2}{9}$, so by symmetry, the total number of edges in $G$ is $3\frac{n^2}{9} = \frac{n^2}{3}$, as desired.

Note that the graph we just described is a very well known construction in extremal graph theory due to Paul Turán, known as the Turán graph $T(n, 3)$.